# Exposing Pure Virtual Class Hierarchy using Boost Python

Tags: c++, python, polymorphism, boost-python

I'm trying to expose a set of C++ classes to Python using boost.python. These classes combine pure virtual methods and shared pointer to achieve a consistent interface through polymorphism, and perform some simple memory management (just enough). Here's the full source:

```
// Boost stuff.
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class RoutingInterface
{
public:

    virtual ~RoutingInterface()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    virtual const char* begin(unsigned int& size, unsigned int limit) = 0;
    virtual const char* advance(const char* data, unsigned int& size, unsigned int limit) = 0;
    virtual void finish(const char* data) = 0;
};

class Route
{
public:

    virtual ~Route()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    virtual RoutingInterface* get_interface() = 0;
    virtual void release_instance(RoutingInterface* instance) = 0;
};

class Router
{
public:

    // Useful types.
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Route> route_ptr;

private:

    std::map<std::string, route_ptr> Routes;

public:

    // Working with routes.
    void add_route(std::string path, route_ptr route)
    {
        Routes[path] = route;
    }

    void remove_route(std::string path)
    {
        auto found = Routes.find(path);
        if(found != Routes.end())
        {
            // Found a nothing.
            Routes.erase(path);
        }           
    }

    route_ptr route_path(std::string path)
    {
        auto found = Routes.find(path);
        if(found != Routes.end())
        {
            // Found a nothing.
            return found->second;
        }

        // Found a nothing.
        return Router::route_ptr();
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(http_server)
{
    class_<RoutingInterface, boost::noncopyable>("RoutingInterface", no_init)
        .def("get_interface", pure_virtual(&RoutingInterface::begin))
        .def("release_instance", pure_virtual(&RoutingInterface::advance))
        .def("release_instance", pure_virtual(&RoutingInterface::finish));

    class_<Route, boost::noncopyable>("Route", no_init)
        .def("get_interface", pure_virtual(&Route::get_interface),
            return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>())
        .def("release_instance", pure_virtual(&Route::release_instance));

    class_<Router, router_ptr>("Router", init<log_ptr>())
        .def("add_route", &Router::add_route)
        .def("remove_route", &Router::remove_route)
        .def("route_path", &Router::route_path,
            return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
}
```

I will implement classes which inherit from the Route and the RoutingInterface classes, and are constructed by factory methods which will then be called from Python. The Router class is a container that stores routes and allows them to be searched from.

Here's the problem: I haven't been able to expose the 3 classes described to Python, and come up with something that will actually compile. I've tried various permutations, most recently the attempt shown in the source above (doesn't compile). Any ideas?

Comment: Could you still simplify the example and then post the full source so we can compile.

Comment: I've modified the question to include a full source example.